# Import range query formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, formula

[image]

Hello I need help with a formula. I want to pull certain information from all 3 sheets and putting it on another google sheet spreadsheet.
Example of the info I need is all  of Driver Bs information from Column A, E, F, H, I, K from week 6.There is more information on Sheet 2 and 3 from that week also that needs to be pulled.

I have this idea for the formula. I put U without a number next to it because there is rows of information constantly  being added to the google docs.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https google sheet goes here","Sheet1!A1:U" "Sheet2!A1:U" "Sheet3!A1:U"}, "where Col4 = 'Driver A'", "where Col21 = '6'", 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0", "Sheet1!A1:U"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0", "Sheet2!A1:U"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0", "Sheet3!A1:U")}, 
 "select Col1,Col5,Col6,Col8,Col9,Col11 
  where Col4 = 'Driver A'
    and Col21 = 12", 1)
```

[image]